# haskell-mode not able to find GHC installation

Tags: haskell-mode

I installed `haskell-mode` and I want to launch the REPL GHCi with the command `C-c C-z`.

However, on typing `C-c C-z`, it shows error `Could not find any installation of GHC.`

[image]

And when I use same command again, it launches a new window with what looks like ghci. But when I try to type and execute something, it shows an error "haskell-process" has died as below. (If it matters at all, there is a `tests.cabal` in the directory where the current open file resides)

[image]

If I enter `y` then it throws the same error as above about GHC not being found.

Now I have my GHC, Stack, Cabal, and HLS installations managed through GHCup. Therefore by default, I only have the ghcup path in the system `PATH` variable.

Since many places online said that there needs to be the ghc path in the `PATH`, I added the line `export PATH=$PATH:/home/axiom/.ghcup/bin/ghc` to my `.bashrc`. But this didn't fix anything.

Further, I looked for other solutions and tried two more things:

I added the following lines in my `.emacs.d/init.el` :

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat "/home/axiom/.ghcup/bin/ghc" (getenv "PATH")))
(setq exec-path (append '("/home/axiom/.ghcup/bin/ghc") exec-path))
```

Adding this also didn't solve anything.

Then I replaced the above lines with `(setq haskell-process-path-ghci "/home/axiom/.ghcup/bin/ghc")` and this didn't help either.

I think the error `Could not find any installation of GHC.` is being returned from a piece of code in this file https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/blob/master/haskell-customize.el but I am not able to figure out how to fix my system according to what the `haskell-mode` code is trying to do before throwing the above error.

Comment: `PATH` and `exec-path` are lists of *directories*.  My impression is that you are adding the path to the specific executable, rather than its parent directory.

Comment: Duplicate of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/77934/why-is-getenv-not-working-to-read-an-environment-variable-in-my-macos-machine (and many others).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is getenv not working to read an environment variable in my macOS machine?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/77934/why-is-getenv-not-working-to-read-an-environment-variable-in-my-macos-machine)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after switching to ghcup.

As the comments pointed out, using directories to `ghci` rather than the executable itself solves the problem:

```
(let ((my-ghcup-path (expand-file-name "~/.ghcup/bin")))
  (setenv "PATH" (concat my-ghcup-path ":" (getenv "PATH")))
  (add-to-list 'exec-path my-ghcup-path))
```

(tested under Ubuntu 22.04)