# shell-command-on-region doesn't execute an executable script named in exec-path

Tags: shell-command, mac

I am on MacOS (12.6.1, Monterey) running Emacs 29.1 (installed from https://emacsformacosx.com). I have a set of shell scripts that I have often use with `shell-command-on-region` (`M-|`); the scripts are all stored in a `~/bin`.

While this worked previously, I now need to enter the full path for this command to work. (I need to enter `~/bin/script.sh` rather than just `script.sh`.)

What is weird is that tab completion for these scripts works in the minibuffer; and if I inspect the variable `exec-path`, the appropriate directory is there. (If I'm in a shell, I can just use the script name.) If I use the full path for a script (`~/bin/script.sh`) with `shell-command-on-region`, that works too. But if I use just the script name I get this error: `zsh:1: command not found: script name.sh`

So, is there some variable other than `exec-path` that `shell-command-on-region` uses that needs to be set? Mac recently switched its default shell from bash to zsh--could that somehow be the cause?

Answer (score 2):

When you use a `shell-command*` function in Emacs, the program that *Emacs* runs is a *shell*, rather than the program you've named in the shell command.  It's the shell which needs to know how to find and run your command, not Emacs.  Emacs only needs to know where the shell is.

Emacs will pass <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `process-environment` to the inferior processes it starts, which includes a `PATH`, so the shell will inherit that (as well as reading the appropriate shell config files which might also manipulate such things).

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @phils for the suggestion, which made me realize that `shell-command-on-region` is somehow not having the PATH variable set for the process. With that hint, and a little more googling, I found another question & answer (linked below) that has a solution; add `(setq shell-command-switch "-ic")` to my `.emacs`, so that inferior shell processes spawn as interactive and (if I understand) run the appropriate dot files. This works, though why this is necessary (and why the spawned shell is not inheriting the PATH in the way @phils describes) is not clear.

- [Is there a way to get my emacs to recognize my bash aliases and custom functions when I run a shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224909/is-there-a-way-to-get-my-emacs-to-recognize-my-bash-aliases-and-custom-functions)

Comment: The shell certainly *should* be inheriting PATH from `process-environment` as described.  E.g. compare: `emacs -Q --batch --eval '(shell-command "echo $PATH")'` vs `emacs -Q --batch --eval '(setenv "PATH" "foo:bar")' --eval '(shell-command "echo $PATH")'`

Comment: Note that you can manipulate `process-environment`, but it is *initialised* from the environment Emacs knew when it was started.  A common problem I see here on E.S. is the user not starting Emacs from a shell and yet wanting it to know about environment values which are only being set in their shell config files.  E.g. setting PATH in ~/.bashrc and expecting Emacs to use that PATH without having started Emacs via bash.

Comment: In addition to phils' answer and comments above, you might find [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/77934/why-is-getenv-not-working-to-read-an-environment-variable-in-my-macos-machine/77937#77937) useful to help you understand how environments are inherited (in particular, it is quite clear why adding the "-i" switch makes the whole thing work, but if you set up the initial environment of a process properly, it should *not* be necessary - however, as @db48x says, most people just don't understand how environments are inherited).