Why doesn't Emacs read my .profile?
I was having trouble launching cargo with M-x compile, and IIUC this meant the compile didn't had cargo in its path. This meant process-environment didn't contain cargo, and this in turn meant it didn't load it from .profile (it behaves like a non interactive shell, so .bashrc is not sourced). However, my .profile DOES contain a export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH" just at the end, yet C-h v process-environment didn't read it. Why? Thanks.

Related (if not a duplicate): https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/77934/why-is-getenv-not-working-to-read-an-environment-variable-in-my-macos-machine

"Why doesn't Emacs read my .profile?" - I know that's a rhetorical question, but it invites answers like: "Why should it?". Should it read .login as well, just in case you use csh? Or .zprofile/.zlogin for zsh? The related question has a good explanation of how processes inherit their environment: that's what you should have titled your question.

What OS are you using?

Forgot to mention, you're right: I'm on Ubuntu 24.04. @NickD shouldn't it read .profile? For what I read (please correct me if I'm wrong), when spawning subprocesses Emacs tries to read the environment, and that means starting a non interactive shell. Note that I also try to manually add cargo to exec-path, but it doesn't help.

"when spawning a subprocess... that means starting a non-interactive shell" - no, that's wrong: you can start a subprocess without the help of a shell: see man fork and man exec - in fact, if you needed a shell to spawn a subprocess, how would shells themselves start one? But even if you use a  bash shell to spawn a subprocess, but that shell is not a login shell, it won't read your ~/.profile. See the INVOCATION section of the bash man page.

Thanks, it's clearer now. This still leaves open why it isn't found even if exec-path contains it, but I'll investigate and open a new question if needed.
